# Android Emulator shows "Your connection is not private" error is the browser

Tags: android-emulator

My Android Emulator's browser shows "Your connection is not private. NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error when I am at work. But when I am at home (no firewall) it works fine. How can I fix this issue please?

I have already allowed emulator.exe and Android Studio through the firewall from the control panel. But that didn't fix my issue.

Thank you in advance